# vue loading messange twice

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js

i have dotnet core 2.0 app using vue.js with webpack it worked fine until today. I didn't change anything in webpack config and i dont think its related to my components code.

i noticed i have code from vue.js in main.js and vendor.js, and i get nextTick log message twice on my page like vue would fire two times.

any ideas?

[console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5A0Y.png)

my webpack vendor config

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var OptimizeCSSPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = (env) => {
    const extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('vendor.css');
    const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);
    return [{
        stats: { modules: false },
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.js']
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?|$)/, use: 'url-loader?limit=100000' },
                { test: /\.css(\?|$)/, use: extractCSS.extract(['css-loader']) }
            ]
        },
        entry: {
            vendor: ['bootstrap', 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css', 'event-source-polyfill', 'vue', 'vuex',
            'axios', 'vue-router', 'jquery', 'vue-progressbar', 'vue-notification'],
        },
        output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot', 'dist'),
            publicPath: '/dist/',
            filename: '[name].js',
            library: '[name]_[hash]',
        },
        plugins: [
            extractCSS,
            // Compress extracted CSS.
            new OptimizeCSSPlugin({
                cssProcessorOptions: {
                    safe: true
                }
            }),
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ $: 'jquery', jQuery: 'jquery' }), // Maps these identifiers to the jQuery package (because Bootstrap expects it to be a global variable)
            new webpack.DllPlugin({
                path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot', 'dist', '[name]-manifest.json'),
                name: '[name]_[hash]'
            }),
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                'process.env.NODE_ENV': isDevBuild ? '"development"' : '"production"'
            })
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [] : [
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
        ])
    }];
};
```

my webpack config

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const bundleOutputDir = './wwwroot/dist';

module.exports = (env) => {
    const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);
    return [{
        stats: { modules: false },
        entry: { 'main': './ClientApp/boot-app.js' },
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.js', '.vue'],
            alias: {
                'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue',
                'components': path.resolve(__dirname, './ClientApp/components'),
                'views': path.resolve(__dirname, './ClientApp/views'),
                'utils': path.resolve(__dirname, './ClientApp/utils'),
                'api': path.resolve(__dirname, './ClientApp/store/api')
            }
        },
        output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, bundleOutputDir),
            filename: '[name].js',
            publicPath: '/dist/'
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.vue$/, include: /ClientApp/, use: 'vue-loader' },
                { test: /\.js$/, include: /ClientApp/, use: 'babel-loader' },
                { test: /\.css$/, use: isDevBuild ? ['style-loader', 'css-loader'] : ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ use: 'css-loader' }) },
                { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=25000' }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
                context: __dirname,
                manifest: require('./wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json')
            })
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [
            // Plugins that apply in development builds only
            new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
                filename: '[file].map', // Remove this line if you prefer inline source maps
                moduleFilenameTemplate: path.relative(bundleOutputDir, '[resourcePath]') // Point sourcemap entries to the original file locations on disk
            })
        ] : [
                // Plugins that apply in production builds only
                new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
                new ExtractTextPlugin('site.css')
            ])
    }];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

*Note: I have never used Webpack and Vue not recently, so maybe what I am saying is complete garbage.*

If you take a look at the very right of your screenshot, you can see where the log messages are coming from. One is from `vue.js` and the other from your generated `vendor.js`. You might still have a script tag that loads the normal `vue.js` file.

I'm not sure whether this has any effects on your code, since the `Vue` variable (used to create the apps, if I recall correctly) should just be overwritten by whatever is loaded last.